# Why does Jake go to the Albacore Club?

Tags: plot-explanation, chinatown

About halfway through *Chinatown*, Jack Nicholson goes to the Albacore Club. Why does he go there?

This happens immediately after the scene where Faye Dunaway comes to his office to hire him to investigate her husband's death, at around 59 minutes. At the end of the scene, Jack hands her a contract and says, "Sign here. The copy's for you."

Then the movie cuts to the exterior of the Albacore Club. Jack walks towards the club, past a flag bearing the club's logo. There's an unidentified man waiting for him outside. They get into a car, and the man drives him to another location, where he meets John Huston.

Why does Jack go to the Albacore Club? Why is there a man waiting for him? Why does he agree to go with the man?